# Find triggered JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, logging, console

I'm working on an existing Wordpress site.

When the browser window is resized so that it is smaller than a certain width, the menu disappears. That's due to some functionality that makes the page pretty on mobile devices.

Now I want to know which JavaScript function is responsible for this hiding. Is there some kind of plug-in or some console that shows all executed JavaScript functions?

Comment: it's more likely CSS's media queries altering the look, not JS. Use the profile tool to log all JS function calls.

Comment: @dandavis You're right, it's CSS! How can I find out what mark-up is the culprit?

Comment: @dandavis Got it! Please convert your comment to an answer so I can tick it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis)' comment is the answer:

> it's more likely CSS's media queries altering the look, not JS. Use
>   the profile tool to log all JS function calls.